# Java - quidditch program using arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I am supposed to create a quidditch program using arraylists but I am kinda confused and my teacher isn't helpful whatsoever. I know how to create the array list and add them, remove, the basic uses of array list. The way he has the directions worded confuse me, any help about where to start would be great.

I can do most of the work for this program, 
the main confusion for me is part a, how to pair the teams to go against each other and how to do the multiple rounds.

Im not asking for anyone to do this program, I'm just asking for some help, explanation and pointers on where to start. Thanks a lot guys.

Directions:

1. Create an ArrayList of Strings containing the names of your 8 ‘teams’.  Use humorous names for your teams (Dwarves, Wizards, Dinosaurs, etc.)
2. Code a method public void playGame(int teamA, int teamB, ArryList teams)

a.  teamA and teamB are the indices (sic. Indexes) of the teams that are playing the current game.  You will use these to retrieve the String name of the team.
For our purposes a Quiddich game has four quarters:

b.  Each team randomly scores 0 to 4 goals worth 10 points each per quarter (0 – 40 points per quarter.
c.  Each quarter, there is a 15% chance that a team will capture the Golden snitch. If that happens the game ends immediately and that team wins. 
(First determine if a team got the snitch, then if one did randomize which one wins with even probability.)

d.  The method should display the results for each quarter that is played and indicate the final score or if the teams won by capturing the snitch.

e.  There are no ties. Play additional sudden death quarters until one team wins.

f.  Your method should remove the loosing team from the ArrayList and print a msg that that team (using the String name) has been eliminated from the Tourney.

3. Code your main program to display the list of teams. Then run the tournament.  For each round pit every other team against one another. 
   a.  First round: 4 games reduces teams to 4 remaining.
   b.  Second round: 2 games reduces teams to final 2
   c.  Final round: 1 game determines the tournament winner.

Each time show the list of remaining teams and use your method to run the games for that round. (Hint: just use even/odd indices for the pairings: Team index 0 plays team index 1, team index 2 plays team index 3, etc.)

Comment: Please read why [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) is not a good question for this site, then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: lol all I asked for were some explanations but alright guess I'll find some other help.

Comment: Aside: *"indices (sic. Indexes)"*.  Look it up in a good dictionary.  Your teacher's use of English is **correct**.  Indices is a plural form of index.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is in the last point - the teams shouldn't play in a "league" way (one vs all others) but in a "cup" way (the one that loses won't play anymore). The teams should be divided like this: even vs odd. I believe the simplest way to do this would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i = i + 2) {
    playGame(i, i + 1, teams);
}
```

Assuming, that there will be even number of all teams of course.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start there!